# Bootstrap loader synchronization error

Tags: ubuntu, tinyos

I'm workin with tinyos 2.1.1 on ubuntu 10.04.
When i make an application on telosb motes, i have the following error:

```
mkdir -p build/telosb
    compiling BlinkAppC to a telosb binary
ncc -o build/telosb/main.exe  -Os -O -mdisable-hwmul -fnesc-separator=__ -Wall -Wshadow -Wnesc-all -target=telosb -fnesc-cfile=build/telosb/app.c -board= -DDEFINED_TOS_AM_GROUP=0x22 -DIDENT_APPNAME=\"BlinkAppC\" -DIDENT_USERNAME=\"nouha\" -DIDENT_HOSTNAME=\"nouha-laptop\" -DIDENT_USERHASH=0xa148eec0L -DIDENT_TIMESTAMP=0x4f4a8ec6L -DIDENT_UIDHASH=0x7900daeeL  BlinkAppC.nc -lm
    compiled BlinkAppC to build/telosb/main.exe
            2648 bytes in ROM
              54 bytes in RAM
msp430-objcopy --output-target=ihex build/telosb/main.exe build/telosb/main.ihex
    writing TOS image
cp build/telosb/main.ihex build/telosb/main.ihex.out
    installing telosb binary using bsl
tos-bsl --telosb -c /dev/ttyUSB1 -r -e -I -p build/telosb/main.ihex.out
MSP430 Bootstrap Loader Version: 1.39-telos-8
Mass Erase...

An error occoured:
Bootstrap loader synchronization error
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

Have you a solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this all the time on my Debian box; usually after disconnecting and reconnecting a mote and trying a new upload. It seems like the USB/serial drivers does not properly release the serial port when you disconnect, so you need a way to tell Linux that the serial port really is ready to be used.

The way I did it was to install "cutecom" (a quite good serial terminal which can display hex values). When I use this program to first "Open" and immediately "Close" the respective ttyUSB, then Linux sees the port as ready and I can upload all I want (till the next time i reconnect the mote...)

Comment: when i use cutecom, the following error appear :

tcgetattr() 2 failed
tcgetattr() 3 failed
tcsetattr() 1 failed
tcgetattr() 4 failed
tcsetattr() 2 failed
*

Comment: Are you sure you have the proper credentials to access the serial port? Have you tried "sudo make telosb install"?